# Can different enumeration values implement different interfaces?

Tags: java, enumeration

Hi,

is it possible that different enumeration values implement different interfaces (like it's possible that different enumeration values implement different methods)?

Reason I'm asking: I currently have a class with a set of `public static final` properties which each share a common interface but also need a different interface somewhere else in the code.

```java
public interface Wrapper {}
public interface StringWrapper extends Wrapper {}
public interface IntegerWrapper extends Wrapper {}

public final class EnumerationOfWrappers {
    public static final StringWrapper ONE = ...;
    public static final IntegerWrapper TWO = ...;
}

public class SomeOtherClass {
    public String get(StringWrapper w);
    public Integer get(IntegerWrapper w);
}
```

I cannot use generics because of type erasure but using `public static final` properties instead of enumeration constants seams dirty. I could of cause name the methods `getString` or `getInteger` but this seams unnecessary.

-- ooxi

Comment: I think so, too, but I'm not sure (or maybe there is another elegant way?)

Comment: Just try and see what happens.

Comment: @Ray try what? The approach I postet does work but is not very nice. I tried `ONE implements StringWrapper` in the `enum` but that does not compile

Answer (score 0):

The moment you declare an enumeration (say Color) and its members (say BLUE, GREEN), the type of those members will be defined as the enumeration type (i.e. BLUE and GREEN are of type Color).

In your case; at most you could store the underlying type as a member variable of the enumeration value. Something like this:

```
enum WrapperEnum {
    ONE(EnumerationOfWrappers.ONE), 
    TWO(EnumerationOfWrappers.TWO);

    private Wrapper underlyingWrapper;

    WrapperEnum(Wrapper underlyingWrapper) {
        this.underlyingWrapper = underlyingWrapper;
    }
}
```

Comment: But how would this help distinguishing between `get(StringWrapper)` and `get(IntegerWrapper)`?